# How to use a keyboard shortcut to select a minimized or maximized client in awesome wm?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, awesome

I can use Awesome WM to switch between non-minimized / non-maximized clients using Super+j and Super+k; but I can't seem to do the same with minimized / maximize clients.

How would one do this using a keyboard shortcut?  I always have to reach for the mouse when working with a minimized or maximized client and it's slow and annoying.